# In which folder is FileInputStream looking?

Tags: java, tomcat

I use the line

```
FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream("myfile.properties");
```

to open a properties file without specifying a path.

When running it on Apache Tomcat, the file can not be found.
I placed the file into the root folder of the application.

In which folder is Java looking?

I can not change the path because the code is not by me.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It will look in the folder that is is the result of

```
System.getProperty("user.dir")
```

and this could be anywhere. That depends the current working directory when the tomcat server is started.

Try to load a small servlet that prints that info at loading if you cannot figure out from standard logs or the tomcat start procedure.

Comment: the default directory to search for file using input steam call

Comment: Changing this system properties is a bad idea and won't work. Define an absolute path prefix in your program: `String MY_ROOTT="/my/folder";FileInputStream(MY_ROOT+"/"+"myfile.txt")`

Answer (score 7):

It will look in the working directory of the JVM process, not the root directory of the WAR. Where that working directory is depends on how the Tomcat process was started.

As such, you shouldn't do this. You should obtain references to resources from inside the WAR by asking the [`ServletContext`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html) object (which has various methods to look up resource streams), e.g. from inside a Servlet:

```
InputStream stream = getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("myfile.properties");
```

Also, it's bad practice to refer to resources inside a WAR as actual files. This will only work if the WAR is exploded into a directory structure, and won't work if the servlet contain decided to run the WAR as an un-exploded `.WAR` file. By sticking to the `getResource...()` methods, you keep things neutral and portable.

However if, as you say, you cannot change the code, then that's a problem, because the code is broken and badly written.  You'll need to figure out how to launch Tomcat so that the working directory is in the "correct" place.  That might entail hacking the startup scripts.

Comment: How can I get the ServletContext object?

Comment: @Alex: From inside a servlet, like the answer says.

Answer (score 1):

In general, whenever I have a "where is the JVM looking for this file" type of question, I launch the excellent Microsoft utility Procmon.  Of course, this only works if you're developing under Windows.  Procmon allows you to set filters on many System events, such as file I/O.

This lets you do things like monitor all I/O coming from application whose name you specify, e.g. `javaw.exe`.  You can add path filters, e.g. include all files with names ending  in "`.properties`".  It shows exactly where, on the file system, the JVM is looking for I/O matching your filter.

Here's an example of setting filters.  Here I'm looking for executables named `javaw.exe` and any file whose name ends with "`.xml`".

[image]

And here is the output after running some Java code that is trying to open an XML file (unsuccessfully - note the NAME-NOT-FOUND error):

[image]

The utility is available at [sysinternals.com](https://www.sysinternals.com), which is a Microsoft owned site.

Answer (score 0):

**If I recall correctly:** Tomcat searches the classpath for ALL resources... therefore "myfile.properties" (with no path) would be in any "top" directory in the classpath. The "default top" (if you don't specify a classpath) is WEB-INF/classes; infact I think Tomcat allways (logically) adds WEB-INF/classes to the classpath, even if you don't want it to... haven't played with Tomcat in years.

Answer (score -1):

It usually works by default in the home directory.

In order to read properties, you should use Class.getResourceAsStream(String)

BTW, a more proper place would be META-INF dir